# linq to sql, begin with query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I've a Languages table:

```
LangId LangName
1       English
2       EngTest
3       Germany
```

I want to write a query that shows LangName begins 'Eng'

`var query = dc.Languages.Where(p=>p.LangName.Contains(txtBxLangNameFilter.Text));`

I'm newbie in linq to sql. Can somebody show me how to write?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Contains` test if a string is found in a string at any location. Since you want to test for a string that starts with a certain string, use `StartsWith()`.

```
var query = dc.Languages
              .Where(p => p.LangName.StartsWith(txtBxLangNameFilter.Text));
```

- [String.StartsWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx)

Comment: IIRC, `StartsWith` can fail if this is translating to SQL with a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: @GrantThomas StartsWith will be translated to LIKE

Comment: Can't see that (work network), but I don't think "yes" or "no" is a hard and fast rule here.

Comment: @JW: That's not LINQ to SQL. That's just LINQ. Of course it's supported in straight LINQ, but LINQ to SQL is converted to SQL on the backend. Your test is not being converted to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to change `Contains` to `StartsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Use StartsWith instead of Contains

```
var query = dc.Languages.Where(p=>p.LangName.StartsWith(txtBxLangNameFilter.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `StartsWith()` method here would be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Lang= from language in  dc.Languages
            where language.LangName.StartsWith("Eng")
            select  language.LangName;
```